# Should I send 400 errors if the input breaks my convention?

Tags: http, http-headers

In web programming, in an AJAX system, if I set up my own convention for POST input data, and the client breaks the convention, for example if I insist on JSON input and the client sends non-JSON or broken JSON, is sending a 400 error status correct? Or should I not use that except for actual HTTP protocol errors? I have looked at [the RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), it says

> 10.4.1 400 Bad Request
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>     syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>     modifications.

However, it does not actually say what "malformed syntax" is, HTTP syntax or "my own syntax".

Please note this is not a question about JSON, I am using that as an example.

Answer (score 0):

The RFC you quoted is obsolete. Have a look at http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-26.html#status.400.

That being said, a more specific status code that might work for you is 422.